# groovy run() method documentation and purpose

Tags: groovy

What is the purpose of the default "run" method in groovy ?. i have read several text books found none of them  describe using the run() method as a supported technique for invoking Groovy scripts (from other Groovy scripts).There are various supported techniques (e.g., GroovyShell, GroovyClassLoader, explicit call to Groovy script “main” method, etc.).

Comment: Which default `run()` method?  The one in `groovy.lang.Script` as [documented here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html#run%28%29)?

Comment: @tim_yates groovy.lang.Script run method  what the usage of this ? confused, it suppose to call second script from first,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to run groovy code is to have your class implement `Runnable`.  When you invoke `groovy MyRunnable` at the command line, groovy will create an instance of your class and call the `run()` method.  See the docs at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running#Running-RunningGroovyscriptsfromthecommandline